# web scraping a drop down menu in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the get CNSs drop down menu from the [following page](http://pipeline.lbl.gov/tbrowser/tbrowser/?run=u233-9GR6Sl35&base=DLLHh27n#&base=1134&run=u233-9GR6Sl35&pos=496:1-14188&indx=0&cutoff=50)

Just to walk you through, I start of with a main link that links to all the sequences(link from a above is an url to a sequence).

> I go to that link and try to grab each item from the drop down menu
>   that takes you to a different page(This is the main issue, that I'm
>   trying to solve).

Once on the page that the drop down menu takes you, I want to grab the link that directs you to get all CNSs alignments and scrape the information that the link provides you. I have to do this for 10000 alignments.

I'm currently struggling with the drop down menu everything else I should be able to figure out.

I've tried implementing Selenium and BeautifulSoup as you can tell from the code I've written so far. I'm open to suggestions and modification.

This is python2.7

Thank you

```
#importing libraries
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#parsing the html
url = ("http://pipeline.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/textBrowser2?act=mvista&run=u233-9GR6Sl35")
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

#saving the links to a list so I can access those links and scrape them 
sequenceurl=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a', string ="VISTA-Point"):
    sequenceurl.append(link.get('href'))

for item in sequenceurl:
    print item

print

#open the webpage and go to the web browser

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(sequenceurl[0])
driver.maximize_window()

Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="x-auto-131"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select')).select_by_index(1).click()
```

Edit: The main link is the link inside the code that says url =. Here it is again for reference http://pipeline.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/textBrowser2?act=mvista&run=u233-9GR6Sl35

Comment: " main link that links to all the sequences ". could you provide that link?

Comment: @MattM. Here is the link http://pipeline.lbl.gov/cgi-bin/textBrowser2?act=mvista&run=u233-9GR6Sl35 it is also in the code. It's the part that says url =

Comment: Sorry, missed that.